# When Javascript Enable in Chrome site my JS is not working/ But when i disable JS its working, Why ? i want to on JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My requirement is that I need to ON/Enable JavaScript on some site Okay, But when I keep JavaScript Enable in Chrome site my `another JS (this PopUp on selection)` is not working, But when I disable/Block all JS for the same site the Popup script is working, Why? Rather I want to on JS.

***Now I want to use this Popup script on a webpage, when all other JS is enabled, How to do it?***

But here my problem is when all other JS is enabled, This Popup is not working
So Plz Any Body can solve my issue, many many advance thanks to them.

My Popup Function Code is:

```js
const container2 = document.querySelector('#article_body');
  const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popupContainer');

  // this method is added
  // It gives the text of HTML of selected text :)
  function getHTMLOfSelection () {
      var range;
      if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
      }
      else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
          var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
          return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
          return '';
        }
      }
      else {
        return '';
      }
    }


  container2.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    const selectedText = getHTMLOfSelection(); // First get the raw HTML text
    if (selectedText) {
      //selectedText.split("<").join("&lt");    // Now replacing the < so that browser don't render it
      //selectedText.split(">").join("&gt");   // Also replacing the > so that browser don't render it
      //console.log(selectedText);
      showPopup(selectedText); // using the 'xmp' tags around the text, to show2 the html as it is 
    }
  });

  popupContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.popupContainer')) {
      popupContainer.classList.remove('show2');
    }
  });

  function showPopup(selectedText) {

    // set the selected text as html inside popup2 element
    document.querySelector('.popup2').innerHTML = selectedText;
    popupContainer.classList.add('show2');

  }
```

```css
.popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: Kohinoor Devanagari;
  box-shadow: inset -17px -6px 20px 20px #0c3f41, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  
}
 

.show2 {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.popup2 {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 80%;
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000);
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);transform:scale(.5)
}

.show2 .popup2 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);transform:scale(1)

}
```

```html
<div class="popupContainer"><div class="popup2"></div></div>

<div id="article_body">
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae pariatur eos aperiam saepe, beatae necessitatibus exercitationem, nemo, sit provident possimus debitis modi eligendi repellat iure vitae perferendis? Recusandae accusamus placeat velit itaque quis fuga laudantium debitis, ab eaque voluptatum illo esse incidunt! Quia tempore explicabo sint laboriosam rerum nihil voluptates voluptatibus voluptate iure. Earum magnam blanditiis voluptates quod ex exercitationem reiciendis, iure qui ducimus similique impedit nemo est, quisquam facere id adipisci harum tenetur consequuntur illum saepe laudantium. Suscipit facilis corporis natus aperiam! Reprehenderit hic quia natus nisi similique quod fugiat, architecto autem deleniti unde commodi accusamus modi voluptate?
</div>
```

Any Body can solve my issue, many many advance thanks to them.

Comment: JS is working when JS is disabled ..? Please add details to your question, as it is, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i mean to say that when JS is disabled from chrome setting for the some site, Then my external JS Like This PopUp is working okay, But when all JS is enabled for particular some site then this PopUp JS is not working.

Comment: Hope You Understand !

Comment: I don't understand. If JS is disabled from browser's options, then JS is not executed, and your code can't "work".

Comment: So tha is what i am saying, i am executing JS code through Chrome Extension.

Comment: In totally my problem is that  i want to use this PopUp script on a webpage, when all other JS is enabled, How to do it ?

Comment: i think some another default js of page is affecting this popup script, then how to solve that ??

Comment: You can try bootstrap modal for popup window. Ref :https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I saw bootstrap, & its really good for popup, But how can i set the text selection function like this JS with bootstrap, Plz help me in detail. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The example is working so it's not clear what the problem is. Can you reproduce the problem in the example?